# Is it a common bug, that the screen turns blue and textures become missing indoors in Fallout: New Vegas? Is there a solution?

Tags: ps3, fallout-new-vegas

I have been playing Fallout: New Vegas quite a bit, despite the following bug.  It occured after only playing for a couple of hours and even persisted after I cleared the game data and reinstalled from the disc.  The bug is as follows.

In area which are either indoors or lit by an ambient light source, the textures will either turn blue (just the texture, not the screen -- this is not the cateye effect) or become missing entirely, leaving gaping black holes in everything.  As you move around, textures pop in and out of existence.

This is quite annoying, but I love the game so I keep playing it.  I experience fewer bugs with NV than with the original, which was crashing on me quite often.

I have an original PS3 60GB fat.

I have researched this question on the net quite a bit, and although I can find many people complaining about various bugs (which I do not seem to suffer from) I have not found anyone complaining about this one.  Is it common?

Perhaps this is just blind hope, but my real question is: does anybody know of a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: I can see this happening on the PC version, but whoa. It's been noted that that New Vegas has had a few problems, though. It's one of the reasons I haven't bought it yet.

Comment: it is really quite upsetting.  I thought it could also have been a corrupt save, so I deleted everything, reinstalled, redownloaded the patch, and then started a new game.  And within two hours it was back.  I can't believe other people aren't having this problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a guess, but I would bet that your video card is starting to break. Being that you have the original 60gb and its lasted this long, I wouldn't be surprised at all. My original 60gb broke about 5 months ago, and you have to remember you are treading on new ground because no one has had a ps3 much longer than you, which might explain the fact that there is little info about this problem on the web. Also, it taking 2 hours to start showing blue textures means it could be heat related. What happens when you start up the game when your ps3 has been off for a few hours?

Comment: I also thought that maybe it was the video card starting to slowly die.  The PS3 stays pretty cool, I cleaned it completely of dust a few months ago.  Regardless it happens even when I've just turned on the PS3... shame, because it is a cool game :).