# What is the install size of Mass Effect 3 on the PS3?

Tags: ps3, mass-effect-3

I have an old 40GB PS3 ( I know ), and it has a ton of game installs, games, dlc, etc on it already.  I'm running low on space and need to know if Mass Effect 3 will require me to move some things around.

What is the hard drive install size of the PS3 version of Mass Effect 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mass Effect 3 does not only have no *partial* install on the PS3, it does not have *any install at all* (unless I severely fell asleep when starting the game).

The actual space required, like with many BioWare games, depends on the size of the save game files, which in turn depend on how far you are through the game.  They won't reach the mammoth proportions of the Bethesda games however, so you should not have to worry.

As general advice however, you should keep a few gigabytes free on your HDD at all times to allow the system some space to swap in and out virtual memory.  You might also want to consider upgrading the HDD or replacing your system.  (I did this recently because of the problem in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19248/is-it-a-common-bug-that-the-screen-turns-blue-and-textures-become-missing-indoo) ).

Comment: I may have worded this poorly in my own answer but you're exactly right - there is NO install.  Rewording my own for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, Mass Effect 3 on the PS3 does not install the game files to the hard drive (this seems like an odd decision to me), so the actual space used is relatively minimal.

**According to the back of the box, the required free space on your hard drive to play Mass Effect 3 is 13 MB.**